# VueJs [vue-router] <router-link>'s event prop is deprecated with <b-navbar-nav>

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using [VueJs](http://vuejs.org) with these dependences:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "v4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.3",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.2",
    "vue-uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

And I have a nav bar:

```
<b-nav-item :to="{name: 'client'}">Client</b-nav-item>
<b-nav-item :to="{name: 'company'}">Company</b-nav-item>
<b-nav-item :to="{name: 'employee'}">Employee</b-nav-item>
<b-nav-item :to="{name: 'product'}">Product</b-nav-item>
<b-nav-item :to="{name: 'provider'}">Provider</b-nav-item>

<b-nav-item-dropdown text="Transaction" right>
     <b-dropdown-item href="client">Account</b-dropdown-item>
     <b-dropdown-item href="#">Settings</b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
</b-navbar-nav>
```

I wish to remove this error that I have on the browser:

```
[vue-router] <router-link>'s tag prop is deprecated and has been removed in Vue Router 4. Use the v-slot API to remove this warning: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link.
```

but I have not found a good solution in order to pass with the router and without to re-loading all the web site like with `href`.

I have also to use `<router-link>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the bootstrap framework but Did you see this link?  https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/363